# How to set permission to see dashboard report (order history, total sales etc) in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, e-commerce, opencart2.x

[Unable to see the dashboard report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P3uE.png)

I have given the user the permissions he needs but I want him to be able to see the dashboard report summary e.g map, total sales, online customers, total orders, latest orders and recent activities.

Comment: go to System > Users > User Groups > Edit. Here you will have a list of permissions

Comment: I know. What do I need to enable to see the dashboard report?

Comment: you need to check the extension/dashboard/x permissions

Comment: @SC92 you should make your comments into an answer.  It's a valid answer.